# Canada’s Global Talent Stream employment and citizenship

Tags: immigration, canada, skilled-migration

I have a job offer from Mississauga, Ontario province, with GTS visa. Can one convert Canada’s [Global Talent Stream](https://www.canada.ca/en/employment-social-development/services/foreign-workers/global-talent.html) employment into citizenship? If yes, at which age it is still possible to do so? I'm 39 now and currently, I'm in the interview process which leads to GTS visa, but not sure if I should accept or better apply for Skilled Worker.

Comment: I suggest to use your offer to apply for PNP and enter to EE pool with 600 pts granted by your province.

Comment: @Zich Thanks a lot! That would be great if you could expand it into an answer with some links to sources.

Comment: Your welcome, Ok, please edit your question and include from which province do you have a job offer?

Comment: @Zich Sorry for the delay. I've just edited the question to include relevant details.

Comment: No need to enter PNP, GTS work permit is still based on LMIA, which already give you that 600 points, no PNP needed.

Answer (score 1):

Other than already having Canadian PR, being in Canada for 3 years, and pass citizenship exam if required, there are nothing you can convert to citizenship. That said, normal work permit with LMIA will almost guarantee getting the PR. Work permit through GTS is just normal work permit - requiring LMIA - so you should be able to start PR process with that.

With work permit you will apply using Skilled Worker category, but that category currently only accessible through [Express Entry](https://www.canada.ca/en/immigration-refugees-citizenship/services/immigrate-canada/express-entry.html). Therefore, the process you are looking is somewhat like this:

1. Get hired and wait for your employer to mail you documents you needed to apply for work permit, which include a copy of LMIA. Make copies of everything.
2. Apply for work permit
3. In paralel of no. 2 above, you can start creating and submitting your profile for [Express Entry](https://www.canada.ca/en/immigration-refugees-citizenship/services/immigrate-canada/express-entry.html). Make sure you give contact addresses that will work for foreseeable future, preferably in Canada; e.g. don't give address and phone of a rental dwelling that you may leave out in few months.